# Is there a way to use AudioContext in a web worker

Tags: web-audio-api, web-worker

I relatively new to web workers (simply had no need until now) and I did a lot of research and think I get the basics...

But :-)...

I'm stuck and hope for definitive input.

I'm rendering a graphic representation of an audio-file with the WebAudioAPI into an SVG. NO rocket science and it works to my satisfaction. With larger Audio-Files however it would be great to do it an web worker, The problem I have is however that inside a web worker I do not have access to the window object, and therefore I cannot access the AudioContext, which I would need to decode the raw data into an AudioBuffer. Is there another way to do it or a way around?

Comment: For anyone looking to process audio in a worker, look into WebAudio Worklets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_AudioWorklet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use WebAudio in a Worker.  You will have to use the main thread with WebAudio and then transfer the data you need to the worker.

But see also the spec issue on [supporting AudioContext in a Worker](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api-v2/issues/16)